# OpenText XMLExport url filtered on specific object type

Tags: opentext, livelink

I get the content of a specific folder using XMLEXPORT url:

```
cs.exe?func=ll&objid=1234&objAction=xmlexport&scope=sub
```

This url returns the full content of the folder. I'd like to have only the folders (objtype 0)

Is it possible with this method? (An attribute like 'objtype=0')

Answer (score 1):

You are probably better to use the search api - you can get access to the subtype and parent id like so:

`/otcs/llisapi.dll?func=search&lookfor1=complexquery&where1="OTSubType":"0"&boolean2=and&where2="OTParentID":"[root object id]"&goFor=[no of items to retrieve]&outputformat=xml`

You won't know how many results to expect at first, and Content Server will return paged results by default - either make one call with `no of items to retrieve` a huge number, or two calls - one with `no of items to retrieve` equal to 1 and the second with it equal to `Output.SearchResultsInformation.RawTotalResults`.

`OTSubType` and `OTParentID` may not be searchable fields in your instance. You can find what fields are available to search by going to the Content Server Administration -> Search Administration -> Configure Search Filters screen, and clicking the Search Manager administration page link.

If you have a login to knowledge.opentext.com, the search api help for opentext content server 10.5 is [here](https://knowledge.opentext.com/knowledge/piroot/llessrc/v100500-1509/llessrc-pgd/en/html/_manual.htm).

Note that this will only give one level of results - not a tree like your XMLEXPORT url does. If you need something more sophisticated, maybe you could write a livereport and get it as xml.